# Take an image(no jpeg format)

Tags: android, image, camera

I want to know if it's possible to take a picture from the camara with the method:

```
mPreview.getCamera().takePicture(shutterCallback, null,jpegCallback);
```

which isn't a jpeg format.
And with a raw method the byte array is null and doesn't works.
If someone knows how to take an image with non-compress format(like jpeg) I would appreciate it. :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)  bitmap.compress

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to set camera parameters like:

```
        c = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);
        //params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);
        c.setParameters(params);
```